# Android & jar file compatibility

Tags: android, mysql, jar, dalvik

How does one find out if a jar is Android compatible, meaning it does not contain imports from class not contained in Android.jar?

I'm trying to build a app that uses the MySQL J connector thingy (and YES, I know about SQLite's existence, but i need the MySQL thingy to work - for remote querying) and when i add the external jar, i get:

> Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1

I've done my Googling and found this article:
http://bimbim.in/post/2010/09/24/Reason-of-Conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1.aspx
which states, as most answers given on stackoverflow on similar problems that i should: remove all jars, clean project, fix-project-properties.

Did this, but problem persist so I'm assuming that somewhere in this jar there is a class that uses an import that android.jar's java doesn't contain... but i could be wrong, i usually am.

So... Anyone?

Comment: Make sure you don't have a copy of the jar accidently copied in one of the source folders of the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to use the MySQL connector in Android. You need to create a layer on the server that is hosting your MySQL.

I read about the reason why Android and MySQL can't directly talk to each other, but of course I can't find the post, so you'll have to do with my answer :P

Check out this tutorial out on how to use a php script to process MySQL tables to JSon:

http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/connecting-mysql-database

Comment: you are right...It seems that I need to implement a REST-full architecture. And regarding my original question... Yes MySQL j/connector does contain some imports not contained by android's java... like some from java.sql and probably others

Comment: My conclusion: if you get the "Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1" and the cleaning project procedure doesn't help... you're added jar has, like in my case, some imports not contained in android's java.

Answer (score 0):

The source code is included with the MySQL J connector download. Is it possible to use the source and build and compile java code for Android?

Answer (score 0):

Try building the project from the command line.

(assuming you have ant, and the `android` tool that comes with the sdk is in your path)

```
android update project -p . -t android-10
ant debug
```

(use whatever android target level your project needs, for the -t option)

If this succeeds, then your problem has something to do with eclipse, not a problem with the jar you are using. And if it fails, it will likely give you a more helpful message than "Conversion to Dalvik format failed".